# drop duplicate rows from pandas dataframe where only a part of column's are same

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas dataframe

```
    p_id c_id_x    c_id_y
     3     13        13
     4     45        63
    37     21        36
     5     13        13
     4     15        67
    34     21        30
```

i want to drop rows where **c_id_x and c_id_y** are same.
(i.e. `3 13 13`  and   `5 13  13`)

i tried using 
`df.drop_duplicates()`
but i won't work since all the columns are not same.

(p_id) is different.

is there any other way to do it?

Comment: if last value of `c_id_y` will be `21`, it has to be removed, because last value of `c_id_x` is `21`?

Comment: @jezrael yes, it has to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df.c_id_x != df.c_id_y)
print (mask)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
   p_id  c_id_x  c_id_y
1     4      45      63
2    37      21      36
4     4      15      67
5    34      21      30
```

Another solution with [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) instead `!=`:

```
mask = (df.c_id_x.eq(df.c_id_y))
print (df[mask])
   p_id  c_id_x  c_id_y
1     4      45      63
2    37      21      36
4     4      15      67
5    34      21      30
```

Comment: you are right say in last column of last row, c_id_y = 21 instead of 30, how do i remove that?

Comment: can we move this in a chat discussion, so that i  can show you my dataframe for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

use `query`

```
df.query('c_id_x != c_id_y')
```

[image]